# Laravel:An entity has 2 foreign keys how to display that entity which belong to the specific table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have an entity call submission, it has 2 foreign key users and task.
A user has many submission, submission belongs to many users.
A task has many submission, submission belongs to many tasks.
In my controller

```
public function go_to_self_marking($id){

    $task = Task::find($id);
    //auth user 
    $user = auth()->user();
    $task_criterias = $task->criterias;
    $user_submissions = $user->submissions;

    //user task criterias submission
    return view('criterias/self-marking')
        ->with('task_criterias',$task_criterias)
        ->with('task',$task)
        ->with('user_submissions',$user_submissions);
}
```

In my view

```
<div>
    @if($user_submissions!== null )
        @foreach($user_submissions as $user_submission)
            <object type="text/html" data="{{$user_submission->url}}"
                width="400px" height="350px"
                style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
            </object>
        @endforeach
    @else                            
        <p>No submissions</p>
    @endif
</div>
```

In this way I can show the all the submission, but it cannot achieve that submission belongs to the specified task.
Each of my tasks displays all the submission which links to the user. How can I fix this?

I changed the code  in my controller

```
public function go_to_self_marking($id,Submission $submission){
        $task =Task::find($id);
        //auth user
        $user = auth()->user();
        $task_criterias =$task->criterias;

        $task_submissions =$task->submissions;

        //user task criterias submission
        return view('criterias/self-marking')->with('task_criterias',$task_criterias)
            ->with('task',$task)->with('task_submissions',$task_submissions)->with('submission',$submission);


    }
```

In my view

```
{{--@if(Auth::user()->id == $submission->id)--}}
                                       @if($task_submissions!== null )
                                           @foreach($task_submissions as $task_submission)
                                                <object type="text/html" data="{{$task_submission->url}}" width="400px" height="350px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
                                                </object>
                                            @endforeach
                                        @else
                                            <p>No submissions</p>
                                        @endif
                                    {{--@endif--}}
```

Now the submission belongs to specified task, but every user can access the submission.

Comment: let me clarify your requirement. 'you don't want all the `user_submission` to show in the HTML, insted `submissions which belongs to particular user and a task.` am I right?

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need `submissions` which belongs to particular `user` and a particular `task`.

In your controller function.

```
public function go_to_self_marking($id)
{

    $task = Task::find($id);
    $user = auth()->user();

    // these are the submissions you want.
    $user_task_submissions = $task->submissions()
        ->where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->get();

    ...
    ...
    // rest of the code goes here.
    // send these $user_task_submissions to your view.
    // and iterate over them in your view.
}
```

Comment: Bro, you are awesome!!! I sorted this out because of you!! This stuck me more than 2 hours. But there is no  "()" behind submissions

Comment: Note that `$task->submissions()` and `$task->submission` are two separate things executing two separate codes. I'll try to explain it in short. if you call `$task->submission`, then submission which are belongs to the `$task` are fetch from the database and then you filter those using `where()`.  --continue

Comment: continue-- in my approach `$task->submission()` it doesn't fetch submissions which belongs to the `$task` instead the query is waiting for other conditions to pass. which is `where()` then after all these conditions i execute the query using `get()` function. (I haven't put it in the answer, my bad, i will edit the answer). both approaches gives you the same results but in different ways. See It's all about Database Efficiency. I think you can understand my long explanation :)